# Controlling Tooltip in a QCombobox using QT Designer

Tags: qt, qt-designer

I have created a `QComboBox` in QT Designer.

I just want to display a tooltip, when we point the cursor on the triangular button in the combo box i.e. at the corner most of the combo box.

If I point my cursor on any other location in the combo box, I dont want to display the tooltip.

Can we do this? Like,do we have control over certain portion in the combobox (or) we can set tooltip only for the entire combobox?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:
`[virtual protected] void QAbstractButton::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *e)`

1、calculate `QComboBox Rect`

2、Determine the location of the mouse.

3、Show or hide tooltips.

like this:

```
QComboBox  *m_pQComboBox;
mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent * event)
{
    QRect rect = m_pQComboBox->rect();
    if (rect.x() < event->pos().x() && (event->pos().x() < rect.x() + 5))
    {
        //showTips();
    }
    else if (rect.y() < event->pos().y() && (event->pos().y() < rect.y() + 5))
   {
       //showTips();
   }
}
```

Comment: What is `showtips()` ? I think the answer would be complete only if you added the correct call that shows/hides the tooltips.